# SessionLogs.Initialize(Tap_log); deletes existing log file and creates new one

Tags: opentap-proj

We are Loading TestPlans from an external application, 
when we select a test plan to run from external application, session logs are created normaly, but when we run second test plan with different log path, **then previously created log file is deleted and new file is created in the new location (With old contents appended).** is there any way to avoid deletion of the previously created log file.
We tried Flush,Rename but did not work.

One more , Is there any way to disable sesssion logs, If we didnot do  SessionLogs.Initialize(Tap_log); default file is created inside the execution directory. \SessionLogs\SessionLog 2020-04-29 23-43-05.txt

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Text Log Result Listener (see [here](https://gitlab.com/OpenTAP/opentap/-/blob/master/Engine/LogResultListener.cs)) creates a new log for each test plan execution.

It's not possible to disable the session logs. You can submit a feature request [here](https://gitlab.com/OpenTAP/opentap/-/issues/new?issue%5Bassignee_id%5D=&issue%5Bmilestone_id%5D=) if that is needed. OpenTAP currently  allows a maximum size of session log files of 2GB distributed across 20 files. If the limit is exceeded, old session logs are deleted.